# GetCurrentConsoleFont not declared in scope, what I do wrong?

Tags: c++, winapi, console, windows-xp, mingw

at the beginning I have:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x500 //tells that this is win 2000 or higher, without GetConsoleWindow would not work
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  PCONSOLE_FONT_INFO lpConsoleCurrentFont;
  GetCurrentConsoleFont(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), false,  lpConsoleCurrentFont);
  return 0;
}
```

And undocumented function `SetConsoleFont` works, but `GetCurrentConsoleFont` fails at compilation saying that it was not declared in this scope.

-- edit: changed to self sustained code.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked

Comment: ok, I changed it to self sustained code, is it working ?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realised it was nonsense.  If you're using MinGW, grep the headers to see if this function is actually defined.

Comment: The mingw wincon.h header defines CONSOLE_FONT_INFO but not GetCurrentConsoleFont.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GetCurrentConsoleFont is exported on NT4+ at least, the MinGW headers must be wrong.

Try adding this code after your #include's:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
BOOL WINAPI GetCurrentConsoleFont(HANDLE hConsoleOutput,BOOL bMaximumWindow,PCONSOLE_FONT_INFO lpConsoleCurrentFont);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Your code is also wrong, it should be:

```
CONSOLE_FONT_INFO ConsoleFontInfo;
GetCurrentConsoleFont(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), false,  &ConsoleFontInfo);
```

(Any time you see PSOMETYPE as a parameter you usually allocate a SOMETYPE struct on the stack and pass a pointer to this struct as the parameter)

Comment: Hmm, are you *sure* it's available on versions prior to XP? I realize that the current MSDN documentation often lies about the minimum version, but I can't find any evidence in the older MSDN docs that it was exported by name prior to XP.

Comment: @CodyGray: Yes, I checked export table (This font index design seems a little stupid, probably documented as part of the settlement, sensible Ex versions added in Vista...)

Answer (score 2):

Hans comment above is correct.  GetCurrentConsoleFont is not defined in wincon.h.  Add the following lines to wincon.h to get this functionality:

BOOL  WINAPI GetCurrentConsoleFont(HANDLE, BOOL, PCONSOLE_FONT_INFO );

COORD WINAPI GetConsoleFontSize( HANDLE, DWORD );

GetConsoleFontSize was also missing.