# Determine the character on the console on witch the MouseCursor is on

Tags: c++, winapi, console, mouse

As we all know, the console buffer size is composed like a 2D array. I'm trying to implement `on click buttons` (drawn buttons NOT child windows) but im having an accuracy problem.

Because the `Console Window` is movable and resizable, i have to take the `Mouse Cursor` position relative to the `Console Window` TopLeft corner (I've found a way of accurately doing that in pixels). But now the problem arrives. When i try to find out on which `character square` the `Mouse Cursor` is on, it becomes inacurate (errors of about 3 ~ 5 pixels) and this is a problem when implementing `on click buttons`.

These are the functions i use. Also keep in mind that we need to previously have the `GetCurrentConsoleFont()` declared. (find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866402/getcurrentconsolefont-not-declared-in-scope-what-i-do-wrong))

For ease of testing, I have implemented a little "Draw my thing" game in the main ([see full code](https://pastebin.com/M8MdRB3K)).

```
/** This returns the cursor position relative to any window (not just the console).*/
POINT GetCursPosRelWin(HWND hWindow)
{
    POINT rCoord;

    RECT windowCoord;
    HWND hConsole = GetConsoleWindow();
    GetWindowRect(hConsole,&windowCoord);

    POINT ptCursor;
    GetCursorPos(&ptCursor);

    rCoord.x = ptCursor.x - windowCoord.left;
    rCoord.y = ptCursor.y - windowCoord.top;
    return rCoord;
}

WORD GetCurrentFontHeight()
{
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFO cfi;
    GetCurrentConsoleFont(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FALSE, &cfi);
    return cfi.dwFontSize.Y;
}
WORD GetCurrentFontWidth()
{
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFO cfi;
    GetCurrentConsoleFont(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FALSE, &cfi);
    return cfi.dwFontSize.X;
}
```

So, is there any way of making this method be more accurate?

EDIT: This is the most accurate way i managed to find though it is still not very precise.

```
/** See the full code for a better understanding */
/** In the main function as parameters of MoveConsoleCursor() */
MoveConsoleCursor(
                  (SHORT)((double)(ptCursor.x/GetCurrentFontWidth() - ((ptCursor.x/GetCurrentFontWidth())%10)/10 )), 
                  (SHORT)((double)(ptCursor.y/GetCurrentFontHeight() - 0.5))
                 );
```

Comment: Are you aware that the console provides [mouse input events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/mouse-event-record-str)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your `GetCursPosRelWin` to:

```
POINT GetCursPosRelWin(HWND hWindow)
{
    POINT ptCursor;
    GetCursorPos(&ptCursor);

    ScreenToClient(hWindow, &ptCursor);

    return ptCursor;
}
```

And `MoveConsoleCursor` call to:

```
MoveConsoleCursor(ptCursor.x / GetCurrentFontWidth(), ptCursor.y / GetCurrentFontHeight());
```

This puts cursor in the center of a square, provided the scroll bars are not moved. Otherwise you have to account for the scrollbar offsets.

Comment: I will take care of them since ill set the buffer size equal to the window size.

Comment: It works good but still i don't get why `0.5` ? Does `ScreenToClient` take in consideration the `Title bar` 's height ? I realised that the actual `Title bar` was the most major problem on the Y axis and was thinking how to get its height.

Comment: Yes ScreenToClient does all the magic to bring coordinates to the client window

Comment: Adding `0.5` to the result of an integer division, prior to implicitly converting it to an integer is useless. It doesn't change the result. The damage has already been done when going for an integer divide. If you want `+ 0.5` to have any effect, you need to use floating point division.

Comment: @IInspectable You're right, there is no need to add anything (especially when it adds nothing), the result of long division is enough.